# HTML True or false in editor?

Tags: html

I'm creating a helpful HTML template and would like to do something where you can toggle tags on and off.

I would like to make it simple like ="true" where you change true or false to whatever you want.

Is there a way i could do this within one html file?

Comment: You could make a JS parser that parses the HTML and adjusts it accordingly.

Comment: I agree with @IsabelInc, I see no way to acheive that in pure HTML

Comment: When you mean toggle, you mean you want to show and hide them on command? If so look at [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/show/). You might find want you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to make your template in a way that you can "turn off" some tags or blocks of code, you could use HTML comments to do so, then the template user will be able to comment or uncomment those blocks to "turn then on or off"
For example:

```
<!-- Left Column, uncomment for use -->
<!-- <div id="col"... [the rest of the code] ... -->
```

And the when a person wants to use that block they remove the comments from it and start using it.

You can read more about HTML comments here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp

Comment: I thought about that, but when i saw from the link you showed me you could have multible lines and make then remove it that why it helped me. Thanks! :D